# Convert 2d image(s) to 3d model

Tags: image-processing, 3d

I want to convert images / movies of real objects and scenes into virtual 3d objects. Any free or demo-able end user apps exist?

Linux or Windows.

As input, it should take multiple images. Videos are simply a collection of multiple images even if I have to extract the images with a third utility. So images are a must and videos a plus.

The output should be a 3d model or scene in any commonly used 3d editor format.

For extra bonus points, it should allow the scene to be non-static letting me watch my favorite movie from any angle even if, from the opposite view of the camera I only see untextured polygons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a workflow but all free software, I think that just about all of it is available as a default in [ArcheOS](http://www.archeos.eu/):

1. Process the images to detect the points into a cloud - Python Photogrammetry Toolbox and GUI. *(Available for Linux or Windows - some Windows installation instructions [here](http://184.106.205.13/arcteam/ppt.php))* or [VSFM](http://ccwu.me/vsfm/).
2. Use [MeshLab](https://sourceforge.net/projects/meshlab/?source=typ_redirect) to get rid of spurious points and generate the meshes - *(Available for Linux or Windows)*
3. Load into [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) to generate a 3D model *(Available for Linux or Windows)*
4. Apply textures, *including potentially [video textures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cg5uT6mrXCY)*.
5. Position your camera, lights, etc. and potentially apply motion paths to anything in the model
6. Render in Blender to get a fly/walk/crawl through or use the game engine to allow you to navigate at will, *depending on the complexity, detail and length go on a nice long holiday while the render takes place.*